# как сравнить все элементы массива с определенной границей

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

всем привет

пробую сравнить все элементы массива с определённым числом.

```
df1_col = []

for x in df1_corr.columns:
    if x > 0.19 | < -0.19:
        df1_col.append(df1_corr)
```

не понимаю как обратиться к каждому элементу моего df. Индексы у меня названиями, все перечислять их - запарно. Точно также названиями и столбцы.

Конкретно этот код вызывает ошибку, так как я пытаюсь обратиться к названию столбцов а не их содержимому. Внутри df_corr - десятичные значения

Comment: И всё же непонятно - что именно вы хотите получить на выходе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,1,2], "b":[2,0,1]})
print(df)
```

```
   a  b
0  0  2
1  1  0
2  2  1
```

```
print(df.applymap(lambda x:( x==0)|(x>1)))
```

```
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
```

Answer (score 0):

не очень понятно сформулировано пожелание того, что должно получиться на выходе, но для сравнения значений вот такая конструкция должна работать:

```
(df<-0.19) | (df>0.19)
```